# SQL Procedure not showing xml data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have simple sql procedure, which retrives xml data and shows as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_UTS_RATERECOMM_RECOMMDATA_XML_SET] (
     @RETURN_CODE INT OUTPUT
    ,@RETURN_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(512) OUTPUT
    ,@XMLDATA xml
    ,@UTILITY_NAME NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@USER_CREATED_MODIFIED_BY NVARCHAR(50)


    )
AS


BEGIN TRY

print '1'

select x.value('@UtilityName','nvarchar(50)') as UtilityName,
x.value('@SuggestedRate','nvarchar(50)') as SuggestedRate,
x.value('@Client','nvarchar(50)') as Client,
x.value('@State','nvarchar(50)') as State,
x.value('@CurrentRate','nvarchar(50)') as CurrentRate,
x.value('@AccNo','nvarchar(50)') as AccNo,
x.value('@Savings','nvarchar(50)') as Savings,
x.value('@tempSuggestedRate','nvarchar(50)') as tempSuggestedRate,
x.value('@tempClient','nvarchar(50)') as tempClient,
x.value('@tempCurrentRateSort','nvarchar(50)') as tempCurrentRate
--into tempTable
 from 
@XMLDATA.nodes('/temp')AS TEMPTABLE(x)

print '2'

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SET @RETURN_MESSAGE = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2056), 'ERROR NUMBER :' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ERROR_NUMBER())  
        + ', ERROR ON LINE :' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'')) + ', ' +  ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),''))
    EXECUTE PROC_UTS_APPLICATION_LOG_SET '', 'ERROR', @RETURN_MESSAGE  ,NULL, NULL,''
    SELECT @RETURN_CODE = @@ERROR   
    SELECT @RETURN_MESSAGE = 'ERROR WHILE FETCHING THE STATE RECORD!'
    RETURN
END CATCH
--================================================================================--
-- RETURN SUCCESS TO THE CALLING OBJECT
--================================================================================--
SELECT  @RETURN_CODE = 0
        ,@RETURN_MESSAGE = 'Record Fetch successfully!'
--================================================================================--
-- THE END.
```

I execute this procedure with following statement:

```
PROC_UTS_RATERECOMM_RECOMMDATA_XML_SET 0,'','<DocumentElement>
  <temp>
    <UtilityName>ALABAMA POWER</UtilityName>
    <SuggestedRate>LPS</SuggestedRate>
    <Client>PANTRY, THE</Client>
    <State>Alabama</State>
    <CurrentRate>LPS</CurrentRate>
    <AccNo>0239808014</AccNo>
    <Savings>-65</Savings>
    <tempSuggestedRate>LPS</tempSuggestedRate>
    <tempClient>PANTRY, THE</tempClient>
    <tempCurrentRate>LPS</tempCurrentRate>
    <tempCurrentRateSort>LPS-PANTRY, THE-ALABAMA POWER</tempCurrentRateSort>
    <SellRate />
  </temp>
  <temp>
    <UtilityName>ALABAMA POWER</UtilityName>
    <SuggestedRate>LPS</SuggestedRate>
    <Client>PANTRY, THE</Client>
    <State>Alabama</State>
    <CurrentRate>LPS</CurrentRate>
    <AccNo>7267305034</AccNo>
    <Savings>80</Savings>
    <tempSuggestedRate>LPS</tempSuggestedRate>
    <tempClient>PANTRY, THE</tempClient>
    <tempCurrentRate>LPS</tempCurrentRate>
    <tempCurrentRateSort>LPS-PANTRY, THE-ALABAMA POWER</tempCurrentRateSort>
    <SellRate />
  </temp>
</DocumentElement>','',''
```

But data is not getting displayed.

What can be the problem?

Please guid me.

There is no error or exception in procedure.

Comment: Do `1` and `2` print?

Comment: @Samcd yes it does print all

Comment: @Samcd  yes...but its of no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't correctly corresponds to the XML structure. Try this way instead :

```
select 
    x.value('UtilityName[1]','nvarchar(50)') as UtilityName,
    x.value('SuggestedRate[1]','nvarchar(50)') as SuggestedRate,
    x.value('Client[1]','nvarchar(50)') as Client,
    x.value('State[1]','nvarchar(50)') as State,
    x.value('CurrentRate[1]','nvarchar(50)') as CurrentRate,
    x.value('AccNo[1]','nvarchar(50)') as AccNo,
    x.value('Savings[1]','nvarchar(50)') as Savings,
    x.value('tempSuggestedRate[1]','nvarchar(50)') as tempSuggestedRate,
    x.value('tempClient[1]','nvarchar(50)') as tempClient,
    x.value('tempCurrentRateSort[1]','nvarchar(50)') as tempCurrentRate
FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('/DocumentElement/temp')AS TEMPTABLE(x)
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2253/0)</kbd>**

Note that `@` in XPath/XQuery is used to reference XML attribute, since all you want to get is XML elements you don't need `@` here.

**[output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2253/0)**:

```
|   UtilityName | SuggestedRate |      Client |   State | CurrentRate |      AccNo | Savings | tempSuggestedRate |  tempClient |               tempCurrentRate |
|---------------|---------------|-------------|---------|-------------|------------|---------|-------------------|-------------|-------------------------------|
| ALABAMA POWER |           LPS | PANTRY, THE | Alabama |         LPS | 0239808014 |     -65 |               LPS | PANTRY, THE | LPS-PANTRY, THE-ALABAMA POWER |
| ALABAMA POWER |           LPS | PANTRY, THE | Alabama |         LPS | 7267305034 |      80 |               LPS | PANTRY, THE | LPS-PANTRY, THE-ALABAMA POWER |
```